# php error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I have checked for similar questions regarding the error however they didn't match the issue I seem to be having.

Getting the following error when attempting to insert data into database:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Here is a screenshot of the database table:
[image]

In the HTML a form, with an action of the php file, has multiple inputs with the names: name, surname, DateOfBirth, email, password, confirm-password

PHP:

```
<?php

// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'pptpp' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }

  // Insert our data
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( Forename, Surname, DateOfBirth, Email, Password ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name, surname, DateOfBirth, email, password '])}' )";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


  // Print response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

  // Close our connection
  $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name, surname, DateOfBirth, email, password ']` that's not how it works.

Comment: `real_escape_string` doesn't take arrays/comma separated values as arguments for multiple rows.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could they be stored in php variables and listed in the same format?

Comment: you can't use real escape string on arrays, I had a similar problem when trying to escape an array, I had to do a foreach to escape every single one

Comment: @EthanBristow you need to pre-define the variables with separate calls to the escaping function; there's way around it. You can use PDO's prepared statements in an array though.

Comment: sience you're not using a framework, try to do something like $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']).. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following part

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name, surname, DateOfBirth, email, password ']
```

is invalid for two reasons:

1. `mysqli::real_escape_string()` takes only 1 argument at a time, a string (unless using procedural, `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, then the first is the connection, then the string as the second)
2. The `$_POST` can't be accessed in that way, I highly doubt you have *one* field named all that. You'll have to specify the index, as `$_POST['name']` etc.

The solution is to match each column with the respective escaped value from `$_POST`,
like `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])` for the name,
`$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])` for the email and so on, an example could be assigning it to variables, and using those in the query, as shown below.

```
$name      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$surname   = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
$dob       = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['DateOfBirth']);
$email     = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password  = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (Forename, Surname, DateOfBirth, Email, Password) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$dob', '$email', '$password')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Then you should note that even with `mysqli::real_escape_string()`, it's not secure against SQL injection, and that you should use parameterized queries. An example of that is given below.

```
// Insert our data
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (Forename, Surname, DateOfBirth, Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['DateOfBirth'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
    if (!$stmt->execute())
        die("Execution failed: ".$stmt->error);

    echo "Success! Row ID: ".$stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
} else {
  die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}
```

Usage of PHP error-reporting would've likely mentioned something about undefined indexes when you use the current escape. *Always* (in development) let PHP give you the errors, by enabling error-reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your file.

Also note that storing passwords in plain-text is a big **no**. You should use functions like `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` to properly and securely store your users passwords.

## References

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, SQL injections aren't an issue for now as this is only a test simulation. In your solution how would you lay it out?

Comment: I suggest you learn by doing it the proper way first anyhow, and use parameterized queries right off the bat. I've edited my answer with how to use `mysqli::real_escape_string()` individually, and added a note about password security.

Comment: Thanks very much @Qirel